# regexp extract pyspark sql: ParseException Literals of type 'R' are currently not supported

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, emr-serverless

I'm using Pyspark SQL with regexp_extract in this way:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['id_20_30', 10], ['id_40_50', 30]], ['id', 'age'])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
sql_statement="""
select regexp_extract(id, r'(\d+)', 1) as id
from table
"""
df = spark.sql(sql_statement)
```

But I obtain this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-5b33a47c-6490-4f80-9a97-3acb37f683ec/script.py", line 86, in <module>
    df = spark.sql(sql_statement)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 723, in sql
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1310, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: 
Literals of type 'R' are currently not supported.
```

The result should be

```
+---+
| id|
+---+
| 20|
| 40|
+---+
```

If I remove the `r` it doesn't fail but it creates a wrong result.
If I try this code with Pyspark locally it works (Pyspark version 3.3.0), but when I run this code in an EMR job it fails, I'm using emr-6.6.0 as application.
Do you have any suggestion? I know I could try to not use pyspark sql but I would prefer to proceed with it.

Comment: what is the source and target extraction?

Comment: That's not a problem, the pattern is fine. The error is about Parsing

Comment: it's about replicating the issue -- see [ask], [mcve]

Comment: right! sorry! I updated the question with the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the '\' with '\' and you need two of them.

```
sql_statement="select regexp_extract(id, '([0-9]+)', 1) as id from table "
#or
sql_statement="select regexp_extract(id, '(\\\\d+)', 1) as id from table "
df = spark.sql(sql_statement)
df.show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
| 20|
| 40|
+---+
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! Can you add an explanation on that? Why do we need 3 '\' every '\' in the pattern? What does that mean?

Comment: "strings" escape '\\' as '\' and you need need to escape '\' in what you pass to SQL. so '\\d' in SQL needs to be written '\\d' and in a string that means you need '\\\\d'