# SparkSQL Regular Expression: Cannot remove backslash from text

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have data imbedded in my text fields that I need to suppress. The data is in the format of \nnn where nnn is a 3 digit number. I tried the following:

```
spark.sql("select regexp_replace('ABC\123XYZ\456','[\d][\d][\d]','') as new_value").show()
```

I expected the result to be "ABC\XYZ\", but what I got instead was:

```
+---------+
|new_value|
+---------+
| ABCSXYZĮ|
+---------+
```

I'm not sure what the other characters are after the C and after Z.

However I need to remove the backslash as well. To get rid of the backslash, I then tried this:

```
spark.sql("select regexp_replace('ABC\123XYZ\456','[\\][\d][\d][\d]','') as new_value").show()
```

However it just simply crashed on me. No matter how I try to escape the backslash, it failed. I tested the regular expression on regex101.com and it was fine.

I appreciate **any** suggestions!

EDIT: I tried Daniel's suggestion but received the following errors:

```
>>> spark.sql(r"select regexp_replace(r'ABC\123XYZ\456',r'[\\][\d][\d][\d]','') as new_value").show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 649, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 134, in deco
    raise_from(converted)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException:
Literals of type 'R' are currently not supported.(line 1, pos 22)

== SQL ==
select regexp_replace(r'ABC\123XYZ\456',r'[\\][\d][\d][\d]','') as new_value
----------------------^^^
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What version of `pyspark` are you running (`print(pyspark.version.__version__)`)? My solution was tested and verified on 3.3.0.

Comment: I found a [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72993096/regexp-extract-pyspark-sql-parseexception-literals-of-type-r-are-currently-no/72993995) with the same error where raw strings worked locally on Pyspark 3.3.0 but failed on EMR. Added an update to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the string outside of the `spark.sql` call, you will notice the string has special characters due to how Python handles the backslash in a literal string:

```
>>> "select regexp_replace('ABC\123XYZ\456','[\\][\d][\d][\d]','') as new_value"
"select regexp_replace('ABCSXYZĮ','[\\][\\d][\\d][\\d]','') as new_value"
```

If we add the `r` prefix to the string, it will be considered a "raw" string (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)), which treats backslashes as literal characters:

```
>>> r"select regexp_replace('ABC\123XYZ\456','[\\][\d][\d][\d]','') as new_value"
"select regexp_replace('ABC\\123XYZ\\456','[\\\\][\\d][\\d][\\d]','') as new_value"
```

That looks correct, but if we just supply the raw Python string to `spark.sql`, the exception `SparkException: The Spark SQL phase optimization failed with an internal error.` is raised. In addition to making the Python string a raw string, *we also need to make the strings in the Spark SQL query raw*, which can again be accomplished by providing the `r` prefix (see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-literals.html)) to the strings used within the query, to ensure backslashes are escaped correctly by the Spark SQL parser.

It's a bit odd looking, but the end result is:

```py
spark.sql(r"select regexp_replace(r'ABC\123XYZ\456',r'[\\][\d][\d][\d]','') as new_value").show()
```

And the output is, as expected:

```
+---------+
|new_value|
+---------+
|   ABCXYZ|
+---------+
```

It's also worth mentioning if you call `regexp_replace` as a function directly (`from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace`), rather than within a Spark SQL query, the pattern in the regex seems to be implicitly treated as a raw string. It does not require an `r` prefix - the backslash in the first character class just needs to be escaped:

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("test")\
        .getOrCreate()
    df = spark.createDataFrame([(r'ABC\123XYZ\456',)], ['temp'])
    df.select(regexp_replace('temp', '[\\\][\d][\d][\d]', '').alias('new_value')).show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+
|new_value|
+---------+
|   ABCXYZ|
+---------+
```

## Update

It looks like when running on EMR, raw strings aren't supported in Spark SQL, which manifests in parsing errors. In that case, making the Python string a raw string and adding escape characters to the SQL string should also work:

```py
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("test")\
        .getOrCreate()
    spark.sql(r"select regexp_replace('ABC\\123XYZ\\456','[\\\\][\\\d][\\\d][\\\d]','') as new_value").show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+
|new_value|
+---------+
|   ABCXYZ|
+---------+
```

Note that the string the regex is being applied to only requires a single escape (`\`) for each `\`, whereas the pattern requires two escape characters (`\\`) for each `\`.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! I will test that. The reason I'm using SQL is that I'm querying data. I used a literal value for my example. I previously tried using r before the expression string but I got an error. I'll try it with an r before the entire string as you did. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel,

Thank you SO MUCH for your help! With the examples you gave, I was able to tweak my SQL statement so it would work. Besides putting the r before the select statement string, I had to change the regular expression to this:

```
'[\\\\][\\\d][\\\d][\\\d]'
```

Thank you much!

Aaron

Comment: Sure thing! Glad to be of assistance!