# Why are raw strings not supported in Spark SQL when running in EMR?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

In Pyspark, using a Spark SQL function such as [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html) or [regexp_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html), raw strings (string literals [prefixed with `r`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-literals.html#parameters)) are supported when running locally, but not when running on EMR.

A simple example to reproduce the issue is:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("test")\
        .getOrCreate()
spark.sql(r"select regexp_replace(r'ABC\123XYZ\456',r'[\\][\d][\d][\d]','') as new_value").show()
```

which will run successfully on Pyspark 3.3.0 locally but raises the parsing exception:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException:
Literals of type 'R' are currently not supported
```

when executed on EMR. Looking at the [session configuration options for Spark SQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-sql), there doesn't appear to be any options which would change how raw strings are parsed - the closest option is `spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames`.

Anecdotally, I remember having a conversation with a colleague a few years ago who said something about AWS having an internal custom Spark for running on EMR, but I have not found any documentation to corroborate that. Also, even if that were the case, I imagine they would maintain support for critical features like this.

There also could be a Spark configuration option which I missed during my investigation.

For anyone who may have some deeper insight or recognizes the issue, why does this discrepancy exist?

Thank you in advance!

Related posts:

- [SparkSQL Regular Expression: Cannot remove backslash from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74062338/sparksql-regular-expression-cannot-remove-backslash-from-text) (Developer tried a recommended solution for regex problem using raw strings, but failed with the parsing error on EMR - example code snippet based on this question)
- [regexp extract pyspark sql: ParseException Literals of type 'R' are currently not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72993096/regexp-extract-pyspark-sql-parseexception-literals-of-type-r-are-currently-no/72993995) (*"If I try this code with Pyspark locally it works (Pyspark version 3.3.0), but when I run this code in an EMR job it fails, I'm using emr-6.6.0 as application"*)